# Sorting multiple levels of nesting with lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I can't find exactly what I want online, including similar posts on SO, so am posting as a question.

I have some sample data as follows:

```
[[[c,1,2,3],[c,1,2,3],[c,1,2,3]],[[a,1,2,3],[a,1,2,3],[a,1,2,3]][[b,1,2,3],[b,1,2,3],[b,1,2,3]]]
```

I would like the this to be sorted by the first list value of the inner most level of nesting, giving a final output like so:

```
[[[a,1,2,3],[a,1,2,3],[a,1,2,3]],[[b,1,2,3],[b,1,2,3],[b,1,2,3]][[c,1,2,3],[c,1,2,3],[c,1,2,3]]]
```

Example code I have seen largely seem to centre on using a `lambda` based solution as so:

```
list_to_sort.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
```

However the examples I have seen only seem to be dealing with one level of nesting, rather than two as in my sample data. Can someone please advise on how to amend the above code accordingly?

Thanks

Comment: `list_to_sort.sort(key=lambda x: x[0][0])`

Comment: Does `list_to_sort.sort(key=lambda x: x[0][0])` do what you are after?

Comment: Tried his list with a default `list_to_sort.sort()`. Seems to work. Works with the above mentioned solutions as well !